# Regularly update an 'adopted' table with a local CSV file

Tags: 7, feeds

I need to regularly update a table from a CSV file located on my server. I'm using the [data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) to integrate it with views. I've researched the [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds), and looks like it used to support a data processor, but it seems to have been dropped. The Data API from the data module looks promising, but not much documentation or support. What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Comment: What makes you say the support between the two modules has been dropped? Both appear to be getting worked on, and both descriptions say they work together.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @acrosman. To clarify, what I was referring to was a processor component of the feeds module. It is no longer supported: https://www.drupal.org/node/1420490#comment-5530270. My issue has since been resolved using a ruby script.